# How to split a column in to two subrows in react native

Tags: android, react-native, user-interface, jsx

i have react native ui like this
[image]

my jsx for a component is

```
  <View style={styleSheet.appItemStyle}>
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <Image style={styleSheet.appItemImageContainer} source={{uri: 'data:image/png;base64,'+item.icon}}/>
    </View>
    <View style={{flex:3, flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>

          <Text style={styleSheet.appItemTextStyle}>{item.appName}</Text>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 12, color: "#000"}}>{item.packageName}</Text>

    </View>

    <View style={{flex:1, alignContent: "center"}}>

        <Text style={{fontSize: 15, color:'orange'}} onPress="">COPY</Text>

  </View>
  </View>
```

the problem with this ui is , the package name of the app is shown in another app row, 
for example, in the picture gmail package name is shown in settings suggestion app name, how can i split a column in to two rows, so that my second text stay on the same row instead of new row? i want the element of list view similar to the below screenshot, i want the title and text to be on same row, how can i solve this problem? I have just placed two text elements in a single row, but they tend to appear on next row, why this happens?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The last screenshot is confusing: it shows your list items with item and subItem on separate rows as well.

As I understand you want to split a single row in two columns on a single row. But as the flexbox flex-direction defaults to 'column', your elements inside will be layout in a column. If you add the flexDirection property as below, your Text components will be layout in a row:

```
<View style={{flex:3, flexWrap: 'wrap', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <Text style={styleSheet.appItemTextStyle}>{item.appName}</Text>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 12, color: "#000"}}>{item.packageName}</Text>
</View>
```

Check out this page: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox; it's also useful to do a quick flexbox try-out.

Comment: sorry i didnt have a perfect example to demonstrate what i wanted, what i actually wanted is to make the package name show right below the app name, but there is a lot of space in between and the package name shows above the second app name

Comment: Ok clear. Could you add the details of styleSheet.appItemTextStyle? It looks like it has a property that pushes the subItem towards the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'}}>
   <View style={{flex:1}}>
    <Text>hello 1.........</Text>
    <Text>hello 1.........</Text>
    <Text>hello 1.........</Text>
    <Text>hello 1.........</Text>
    </View>
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
    <Text>hello 2.........</Text>
    <Text>hello 2.........</Text>
    <Text>hello 2.........</Text>
    <Text>hello 2.........</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
```